# Detect object in an image using openCV python on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I have a small project that I am tinkering with. I have a small box and I have attached my camera on top of it. I want to get a notification if anything is added or removed from it.

My original logic was to constantly take images and compare it to see the difference but that process is not good even the same images on comparison gives out a difference. I do not know why?

Can anyone suggest me any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I can suggest a way of doing this. So basically what you can do is you can use some kind of Object Detection coupled with a Machine Learning Algo. So the way this might work is you first train your camera to recongnize the closed box. You can take like 10 pics of the closed box(just an example) and train your program to recognize that closed box. So the program will be able to detect when the box is closed. So when the box is not closed(i.e open or missing or something else) then you can code your program appropriately to fire off a signal or whatever it is you are trying to do. So the first obvious step is to write code for object detection. There are numerous ways of doing this alone like Haar Classification, Support Vector Machines. Once you have trained your program to look for the closed box you can then run this program to predict what's happening in every frame of the camera feed. Hope this answered your question! Cheers!